# Zero subsums of integer vectors

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $[n]$ denote the subset of $2n+1$ integers with absolut value at most $n$.
Consider $k$ (not necessarily different) vectors in $[n]^d$ summing up to zero. What is the smallest $k>1$ (for fixed $n$ and $d$) that assures the existence of a strict subsequence of vectors also summing up to zero?

I am most interested in the case $n=1$.

Comment: Some bounds may be deduced from the case $d=1$ where I believe the answer is about $2n$.

Comment: Could you please clarify if you allow repetions of the same vector? (I am unsure, on the one hand you say 'subset' which suggests not, on the other hand you say for d=1 it should be about 2n which seems wrong without repetition.) 

Comment: Sorry, I allow repretitions. Eg for $d=1$ for the starting sequence $(-1,-1,-1,-1,2,2)$ I can choose $(-1,-1,2)$, but for $(-1,-3,2,2)$ I cannot choose $(-1,-1,2)$ as $-1$ appears only once in the original sequence. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For n=1 we have recently solved the problem, the answer is around $d^d$, see http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0424 By we I mean my coauthors and by solve I mean gave a reasonable lower and upper bound.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see there is a lower bound for m problem. Does your paper also imply that if I have around $d^d$ vectors, then I can found a subsequence summing up to zero?

Comment: I think that follows from the Steinitz lemma.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: In the paper there is a detailed description of how to use the Steinitz lemma to prove an upper bound. The main idea is that if we can order the vectors $v_i$ such that for any $k$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^k v_i$ is in $[-d,d]^d$, then for some $k_1$ and $k_2$ these sums are close, so their difference is also small. Since in your case all vectors are integers, the difference is also an integer, thus the all zero vector.

Answer (score 2):

To complement domotrop's answer with info on the general problem:

Bounds for the general problem (even a more general problem, considering arbitrary prescribed subsets of admissible vectors) were obtained by Diaconis, Graham, Sturmfels ['Primitive Partition Identities'](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/96_02_primitive_partition.pdf).

In addition, for the case $d=1$ the precise value $2n-1$ is established.

The general upper bound is of the form 
$$(2d)^d (d+1)^{d+1} D$$
where $D$ is the largest absolute value of the determinant of any $d$ of the admissible vectors.

Comment: I couldn't resist upvoting...

Comment:  @Artie Prendergast-Smith: yes, I like the result, too. And, thanks for the vote.   

Comment: Thanks! So for n=1 I get more or less d^{3d}?

Comment: @Wajcha: you are welcome! Regarding your question: you could save about a d^(d/2) by using Hadamard's bound to bound the D by d^(d/2) (which can be  optimal). But, of course, it is still much worse than domptorp's bound in this case. 
 